# how to print line with essential words

Tags: c#, .net, forms, web-applications

i made a c# program like this

Form1

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PassingText = textBox2.Text;
        Form2 A      = new Form2();
        A.Show();

    }
```

Form 2

```
           textBox1.Text = "@" + Form1.PassingText ;
```

it is printing like below

when i add ####

it prints

```
@####
```

this is working only for single line when i add something in form 1..

I want to do this for multiple lines with essential words should be printed.

eg.

i will add

9999999

it should be printed as

```
    @999999
    essential words
    words
```

essential words ,words should be printed after a newline like above @9999999

When i add

SSSSSS

GGGGGG

it should be printed as

```
@SSSSSS
essential words
words 
@GGGGGG
essential words
words
```

I have no idea how to do it. Please help me

Comment: Enable Multiline for the TextBox. Use Environment.NewLine to add line breaks.

Comment: I did it , plz try to understand what i said

Comment: Maybe you should be using a ObservableCollection in Form1 for this, if I understand you correctly

Comment: i am very beginner to this job . I can make to print it without essential words ,words  line by line

Answer (score 0):

To Pass essential words from  Form1  to From2, you can make use of constructor and pass value

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PassingText = textBox2.Text;
        Form2 A      = new Form2(PassingText);
        A.Show();
    }
```

Form 2 code

```
    private string passedString_;
    public Form2(string val)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        passedString_ = val;
    }
```

For windows application make use of Multiline Text box. do like this

[TextBoxBase.Multiline Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.multiline(v=VS.80).aspx)

```
textBox1.Text += ("Test \r\n");//or Environment.NewLine
textBox1.Text += ("new line ");
```

try this alos

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuiler();
sb.AppendLine("test");
sb.AppendLine("test new line ");

textbox1.Text += sb.ToString();
```

---

you need to make use of [Environment.NewLine Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) in windows applications and you have to make use of `<br/>` tag for web based application.

and make use of `<textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>` for web application and multiline textbox for windows application.

Comment: yes i tried Environment.NewLine Property to get a new line but i couldn't reach to the target.

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks - is it web application ??? Please share you UI code

Comment: currently it is a C# Form application.

Comment: textBox1.Text = "@" + Form1.PassingText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "@");

Comment: I use this code to get prints for multiple lines. But i cannot add essential words

Comment: thanks. but main problem is how to add essential words after the word that i have entered in form 1.

Comment: when i add PassingText in form 1 it says does not contain a constructor that take 1 argument

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks - you need to add constructor like this  public Form2(string val)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        passedString_ = val;
    } , updated in answer (Previous there is error of this())